AWS glue : How do I create a compressed comma-quote file?
TLDR: How do I create a comma-quote delimited file on an S3 from a dynamic frame, where every field is wrapped in double quotes, with a header row, a CRLF line delimiter and gz compression? No output method I've tried can meet all of these requirements
Apologies for the big info dump, but I've tried a lot of methods to create my file, but nothing has worked.
I need to be able to extract a table from a SQL database, and write it to a file on an S3 location for a client to pick up. This should be pretty basic stuff, but  after trying many different methods, I cannot get the format I want.
The output file needs to be comma-quote delimited. Every field needs to be wrapped in double quotes, regardless of whether the field has spaces of punctuation in it. The file needs to have a header row, it needs to have a CRLF line delimiter, and it needs to have gz compression. All of these things are non-negotiable, because of the client's requirements.
If I write from a dynamic frame, using a glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options, it will only wrap fields in double quotes when the field is a string with spaces of punctuation.
If I convert the dynamic frame to a data frame, I can use QuoteAll,which corrects this issue, but now I cannot have CRLF as the line delimiter. The linesep parameter only accepts one character, so it's either CR or LF
I have tried to build the output row that I want manually, so I've converted all fields in my dataframe to strings, wrapped each one in double quotes, then concatenated them all together into a single field with a comma delimiter. I've also been able to manually create a header row with the old fieldnames in it, and add a CR to the end of each row, so that when the dataframe exports it with a LF, the file will correctly have CRLF as the row delimiter. Again, this all worked perfectly, until I tried to use compression, and apparently I cannot do that if I want to use a dataframe write to create a text file. I can do it just fine if I want to create a csv file, but if I do that, it will escape all of my double quotes, which I don't require.
So as I've now handled all of the formatting myself, I've tried converting this back to a dynamic frame, and tried to use glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options again. Again, the output is almost perfect, and it has the compression I need, BUT it's also outputting the header row. As I'm now building my own header row, I do not require this, but adding in the Header: False option does not appear to work.
Everything I've tried has met 90% of my requirements, but none of these methods have created the file I need. How am I supposed to create this file format? It's all pretty basic stuff
